# Strange Joomla element placing error (css error?)

Tags: html, css, joomla

On this site: http://www.gruene-chemnitz.de/abgeordnete the right sidebar gets placed below the main content. Which of course isn't supposed to happen.

But this is the only page where this happens on the entire site. I'm not able to find the difference or get a clue whats wrong.

I would really appreciate your help in fixing the error.

Edit: The index.php of the used template looks like this:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >

<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/favicon.ico" />
<?php if($this->countModules('left and right') == 0) $contentwidth = "100";
      if($this->countModules('left or right') == 1) $contentwidth = "80";
      if($this->countModules('left') != 0) $contentwidth = "81";
      if($this->countModules('left and right') == 1) $contentwidth = "60";
?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-outer">
   <div id="top"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="xhtml"/></div>
</div>
<div id="page">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="shadow"><div class="shadow"><jdoc:include type="module" name="breadcrumbs"/></div></div>
   <div class="inside">
     <div id="sidebar">
       <div class="insideleft"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml"/></div>
     </div>
     <div id="content<?php echo $contentwidth;?>"><jdoc:include type="component" />
       <div id="footer">&#169;B&uuml;ndnis 90 die Gr&uuml;nen <?php echo date("Y",time());?></div>
     </div>
     <div id="sidebar-2">
       <div class="insideleft"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml"/></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First you have tables based layout. Second your div#sidebar-2 is inside the div#content60. Remove the div@sidebar-2 ouside the div#content60 in your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

check below div control position on your page html source

content60 and 
sidebar-2

i think there is a html break on module with div content60. so check html first.

hope this will help you.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you have tables based layout. Second your div#sidebar-2 is inside the div#content60. Remove the div@sidebar-2 ouside the div#content60 in your HTML markup.

Like for example here gruene-chemnitz.de, the div#sidebar-2 is outside the div#content60 and these two along with div#sidebar are the children of div.inside

Comment: please see my edit in the Question. First of all: I don't see tables there and from what i see, the sidebar-2 is already outside the content area.

Comment: your link "http://www.gruene-chemnitz.de/abgeordnete" and your code above dont match mate. This is what shows looking at the link in IE9 with Dev Tools. <div id="content60"> <table class="blog" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td vAlign="top"> <div> <table class="contentpaneopen"> <table class="contentpaneopen"> <tbody> <tr> <td vAlign="top" colSpan="2"> <div> <div id="sidebar-2"> - And it goes on and on

Comment: And here http://www.gruene-chemnitz.de/, where you have no problems as the sidebar does float to the right of the content, you have the following structure. <div class="inside"> <div id="sidebar"> <div id="content60"> <table class="blog" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"> <div id="footer"> <div id="sidebar-2"> - Here the sidebar-2 is outside the content60. - Do you want a pic of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all occurences of templates blowing apart on specific pages can be traced down to invalid html within an article - or module.

Within your content it looks like you have closed a div that wasn't open - this is then interpreted by the browser as an earlier div as well as closing some intermediate td tags and other things - basically blowing your template apart.

The easiest fix would be to view the source within your article - within the wysiwyg editor and count how many times you open divs versus how many you close.

To give you an idea of where to look use the html validator:
http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gruene-chemnitz.de%2Fabgeordnete